# Playing audio in a Mac App Store compatible NWJS app

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, app-store, node-webkit

In the Additional Steps section at the foot of [MAS: Packaging your app](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/MAS%3A-Packaging-your-app), I read:

> To ensure proper validation [of your NWJS app for the Mac App Store], you have to check those steps:
>
> Delete the FFMPEG library:
>
> `rm "YourApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/nwjs
>   Framework.framework/Libraries/ffmpegsumo.so"`
>
> Note: Currently, FFMPEG library cannot be submitted to Mac App Store as is.

When I delete the FFMPEG library, if my app includes (ogg) audio files and attempts to play them, the app crashes. I assume that this is because the FFMPEG library is essential for audio playback.

Does this mean that the current Mac-App-Store-friendly NWJS build (nwjs-macappstore-v0.12.3-osx-x64) does not support audio? Or is the an alternative audio library that I can use with it?